# Should new users be able to post pictures and more links?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, new-users, privileges, images

I've gone through several questions (just saw this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227678/background-image-will-not-show-on-ios-but-shows-fine-on-other-browsers)) where new users place links to pictures in their questions, and if there are more than two links, they post the additional ones as a comment.

Besides "spam," is there any specific reason for this?

I find clicking on links and going through the comments to find information pertinent to the question, throws off my train of thought, and unnecessary. It literally takes less than a minute for users to flag a question, downvote it, and vote to close it if it is spam, so should these limits be removed?

Comment: To avoid downvotes, you may want to consider why this is in place, and weigh those reasons against possible counters. A more thorough question is likely to encourage more discussion. It is worth noting that people up/downvote to agree or disagree, but if you are concerned, they are much less likely to if your question is thorough.

Comment: In any case those restrictions [are removed after one whole answer upvote (or two on a question)](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user). It's not like a big hurdle, here. Just enough to stop bots.

Comment: This restriction has actually been [lifted on Skeptics SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user) because of the stringent requirements on citing your sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the positive side:

- Users could be posting legitimate questions which need those links
- Users deserve to have decent answers
- It makes the site look cleaner

However, on the negative:

- If they post the links as comments, someone could very easily do them the favor of editing them in.
- If the question is spammy and needs to be edited, it wastes valuable community time
- More user time is wasted by viewing the question, and trying to follow the link
- If the question is decent, then regardless of the links, the community can find a solution
- If a question contains more than two links, chances are decent that it needs to be edited, closed, or removed anyway.

To me, it seems as if this isn't a problem.

Comment: Add to your list of negatives the trolls that we get who would dump quite NSFW images in questions if they could. We had one user just yesterday create four new accounts and attempt to use those to post photos of rather overweight gentlemen. You don't see these because the community shuts them down pretty quickly, but if they could directly embed images in their posts as a new user they would be quite disruptive.